# Best resources to learn shaders for real-time rending

Tags: rendering, real-time, shader

I am looking for a good introduction and reference for learning shaders for Maya and other 3D applications.  I've search around the internet, but seem to have run into problems finding good communities or good resources.

Comment: shaders i general, or specific to the app mentioned?

Comment: Shaders that are more focused for rendering in Maya/3DSmax and the like.  I'm looking to learn about developing shaders for artist inside 3D modeling software instead of trying to make shaders for a 3D engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using OpenGL shaders then the [Orange Book](http://www.3dshaders.com/home/) is your first point of call.  It's remarkably readable.

Somewhat more advanced, [GPU Gems](http://developer.nvidia.com/object/gpu_gems_home.html) is also excellent, highly readable, and treats most of the more common problems in some depth.

EDIT: As per comment about normals then it sounds like you need to get you head around some maths in the area first too.  It's a little old now and some of the early scene-setting chapters are somewhat out of date, but [Mathematical Elements for Computer Graphics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0070535302) is still an excellent text on the concepts and the meat of the book will set you up with a solid mathematical foundation. Make no mistake, this isn't a light treatise but it was the bible for the subject for a good many years.  You might profitably use a text on Linear Algebra too.

Comment: I'm using FX Composer right now which can create shaders that can be used in 3D modeling programs.  I'm running into problems with normals  at the moment... will these books be able to give me a stronger foundation?